# Call of Duty slang “sice”?

Tags: terminology, call-of-duty-series

I have stumbled across the verb *sice* which is reported by these Urban Dictionary [definitions](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sice) to be used in playing Call of Duty:

> Sice is like slice, except for it's sice. Often yelled while playing Call of Duty and using the melee attack to kill an opposing player.
>
> To conduct a knife attack on an opponent or team mate while playing Call Of Duty.

Can anybody confirm these definitions? If they are legit, what part of Call of Duty does that word come from?

Comment: If it's a legit term, I suspect it's something that developed in the multiplayer community, no specific parts.

Comment: Never heard of it. And btw. urban dictionary is not a definitive place to acquire official game terms.

Comment: is nice -> 'snice ?

Comment: To add to Bora's comment, there are (were) "definitions" where friends or people of a community add a definition about a person just to crack jokes.  e.g., `Person X - Can't get a kill because he sucks.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sice could be a combination of slice, i.e. a melee attack with a knife and the sound a knife makes when its pulled from its sheath.

Think of movies when someone pulls a sword out of sheath. What sound does it make? It sounds like "sice".